# Counter Problems

Tags: vhdl

Previously had an issue with measuring four clock cycles, but I believe that my code works but is delayed for a clock cycle.  Another post has gone up with that issue.

Comment: Stop posting the irrelevant noise and begging for HELP in your titles. It's not acceptable or appropriate here. We know you need help, or you wouldn't be posting here. It's not necessary to POST IT IN CAPS in your title. If you want to pray to your favorite deity, do it in your church, synagogue, mosque, chapel, or temple, or whatever is frequented by your faith.

Comment: I'm not religious at all. The problem here is that I've asked this question repeatedly for the last week and have not received any help at all. Understand my frustration.

Comment: So either help or stay quiet.

Comment: Your frustration isn't our concern, I'm afraid. :-) The needless noise and clutter isn't necessary, it's not going to get you help any sooner, and it conflicts with site guidelines against begging or pleading for help. Ask a clear question, tag it with the relevant and applicable tags, and if someone can help you they will. If no one has an answer to offer you, begging and screaming for HELP will not change anything. And you don't get to tell me to be quiet. Rudeness can get a moderator involved, get your account suspended, and remove any chance of getting help. So be polite, or go elsewhere.

Comment: If an account is suspended, another can be created.

Comment: Andi it can be closed as well, particularly if it asks the same question. You're the one screaming for HELP. A delay of days would be more frustrating, I'd think. Stop being a child and start being civil instead. If you can't do so, feel free to ask your question on a different site.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general principle you can adopt when daisy-chaining counters:

```
ENABLE_TO_NEXT_COUNTER <= ENABLED when PREVIOUS_COUNTER=MAXIMUM_COUNT and ENABLE_TO_PREVIOUS_COUNTER=ENABLED else NOT_ENABLED;
```

The check for `PREVIOUS_COUNTER=MAXIMUM_COUNT` is obvious, but we need to `and` in the `ENABLE_TO_PREVIOUS_COUNTER` so that the `ENABLE_TO_NEXT_COUNTER` pulse is only one clock wide.

So, I have changed your second architecture to

```
architecture behavior of counter_4 is
  signal count1, count2, enable2 : std_logic;

  component counter_2 is port(
    clock, reset, enable : in std_logic;
    f : out std_logic
    );
  end component;

begin

  Enable2 <= '1' when Enable = '1' and count1 = '0' else '0';

  c0: counter_2 port map (clock => Clock, reset => Reset, enable => Enable, f => count1);
  c1: counter_2 port map (clock => Clock, reset => Reset, enable => Enable2, f => count2);

  f <= count2;

end behavior;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5BhA

Comment: I've made some changes in my initial post and have run into an issue with the timing.